# How to make moving average across groups?

Tags: stata

```
| month | year   | amount|
|-------|--------|-------|
|  1    |  2010  |  26   | 
|  1    |  2010  |  26   |
|  2    |  2010  |  30   | 
|  3    |  2010  |  35   |
|  3    |  2010  |  35   |
```

I need to figure out how to make another variable, that takes the prior month amount _n-1 and _n and divide it by 2, kind of like a moving average. The problem is that I need to do it by month and year, since there are multiples of the same month and year. There are other variables as well that are irrelevant, but that is why I can't just delete duplicates.

For example, for observation 5, I would need it to be (35+30+26) / 3

Comment: Please see advice at the Stata tag on presenting data examples. Yours is helpful but needs surgery to remove the punctuation. Row and column are alien terms to Stata which talks of observations and variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your prescription and your example don't match at all. Your example is a mean of 3 monthly means, this month and the two previous. Your prescription is a month and the month previous.

Here is some technique that focuses on two possible meanings of your prescription.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte month int year byte amount
1 2010 26
1 2010 26
2 2010 30
3 2010 35
3 2010 35
end

gen mdate = ym(year, month)

format mdate %tm

foreach w in total mean count { 
    egen `w' = `w'(amount), by(mdate)
} 

gen wanted1 = (mean + mean[_n-1]) / 2  if mdate == mdate[_n-1] + 1
bysort mdate (wanted1) : replace wanted1 = wanted1[_n-1] if missing(wanted1)

gen wanted2 = (total + total[_n-1]) / (count + count[_n-1]) if mdate == mdate[_n-1] + 1 
bysort mdate (wanted2) : replace wanted2 = wanted2[_n-1] if missing(wanted2)

list, sepby(mdate)

     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | month   year   amount    mdate   total   mean   count   wanted1    wanted2 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |     1   2010       26   2010m1      52     26       2         .          . |
  2. |     1   2010       26   2010m1      52     26       2         .          . |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  3. |     2   2010       30   2010m2      30     30       1        28   27.33333 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  4. |     3   2010       35   2010m3      70     35       2      32.5   33.33333 |
  5. |     3   2010       35   2010m3      70     35       2      32.5   33.33333 |
     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```